# Firebase token login logic

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I have a simple app which has a Login functionality, I added firebase to this Project to sent notifications. This works so far. So each device with the app has a unique token, user1 get notificationa and user2 gets notificationb, but if user1 logs out of the application and logs into user2 account user1 still get notificationa instead of notificationb. So I Need to delete and recreate a token if the user tries to Login but how do I do that? So far I only read that firebase creates a new token if the app is uninstalled